# using Javamail jar to send email to multiple users in android

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I'm designing an android app that allows users to send invites to friends.

I'm using the Javamail jar for this process.

Everything works fine. However, I want to be able to send the invites to multiple users at the same while modifying he body of the email for each invitee. Using BCC or CC won't work, since the body is never the same.

In my AsyncTask, I'm looping over the the list of TO addresses and sending the email one at time. But, the problem is when the first email is sent, items that is suppose to be in the body of the second message is included in the first email, thus discarding some of the messages that is suppose to in the first.

please how do I fix this?

My code:

```
private class SendEmailTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public SendEmailTask() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(_context);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Sending");
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        boolean result = false;
        String to = "";
        try {
            String body = setting.parseAsset(_context, "email.html");
            String name = _session.getDisplayName();

            body = body.replace("<%NAME%>", name);
            if (items.size() > 0) {
                Mail mail = null; 

                for (String to: items) {            
                    mail = new Mail("test@gmail.com",
                            "Thisisatest1");
                    body = body.replace("<%EMAIL%>", to);

                    mail.set_to(to);
                    mail.set_from("no-reply@test.com");
                    mail.set_subject(name + " has invited you to Test");
                    mail.set_body(body);

                    result = mail.send();
                }

            }

            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SendEmailTask", "Invite not sent to " + to, e);
            dialog.dismiss();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        if (result) {
            Toast.makeText(_context, "Invite sent successfully.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invite(s) not sent.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}


public class Mail extends Authenticator{

private String _user;
private String _password;
private String _to;
private String _from;
private String _port;
private String _socket;
private String _host;
private String _subject;
private String _body;
private boolean _auth;
private boolean _debuggable;
private Multipart _multipart;

public String getUser() {
    return _user;
}
public void setUser(String user) {
    this._user = user;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return _password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this._password = password;
}
public String get_to() {
    return _to;
}
public void set_to(String _to) {
    this._to = _to;
}
public String get_from() {
    return _from;
}
public void set_from(String _from) {
    this._from = _from;
}
public String get_port() {
    return _port;
}
public void set_port(String _port) {
    this._port = _port;
}
public String get_socket() {
    return _socket;
}
public void set_socket(String _socket) {
    this._socket = _socket;
}
public String get_host() {
    return _host;
}
public void set_host(String _host) {
    this._host = _host;
}
public String get_subject() {
    return _subject;
}
public void set_subject(String _subject) {
    this._subject = _subject;
}
public String get_body() {
    return _body;
}
public void set_body(String _body) {
    this._body = _body;
}
public boolean is_auth() {
    return _auth;
}
public void set_auth(boolean _auth) {
    this._auth = _auth;
}
public boolean is_debuggable() {
    return _debuggable;
}
public void set_debuggable(boolean _debuggable) {
    this._debuggable = _debuggable;
}
public Multipart get_multipart() {
    return _multipart;
}
public void set_multipart(Multipart _multipart) {
    this._multipart = _multipart;
}

public Mail() {
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port
    _socket = "465"; // default socketfactory port

    _user = ""; // username
    _password = ""; // password
    _from = ""; // email sent from
    _subject = ""; // email subject
    _body = ""; // email body

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a
    // handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
    MailcapCommandMap mailCap = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap
            .getDefaultCommandMap();
    mailCap.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mailCap.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mailCap.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mailCap.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mailCap.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mailCap);
}

public Mail(String user, String pass) {
    this();
    this._user = user;
    this._password = pass;
}

public boolean send() throws Exception {
    Properties props = setProperties();

    if (!_user.equals("") && !_password.equals("") && !_to.equals("")
            && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

        InternetAddress addressTo = new InternetAddress();
        addressTo.setAddress(_to);

        msg.setRecipient(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

        msg.setSubject(_subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // setup message body
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
        messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Put parts in message
        msg.setContent(_multipart);

        msg.saveChanges();

        // send email
        Transport.send(msg);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


@Override
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _password);
}

private Properties setProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

    if (_debuggable) {
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    }

    if (_auth) {
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    }

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _socket);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    return props;
}   
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by setting mail = null after sending each email

```
for (InviteItem item : items) {
                    Mail mail = new Mail("test@test.com",
                            "MYPASSIFORGOTTOCHANGE");
                    to = ((com.plan.library.contact.Invite) item)
                            .get_email();
                    invitees.add(to);

                    String body = html.replace("<%EMAIL%>", to);

                    mail.set_to(to);
                    mail.set_from("test@test.com");
                    mail.set_subject(name + " has invited");
                    mail.set_body(body);

                    result = mail.send();
                    mail = null;
                }
```

Comment: Just so you know, your Thisis********* password completely worked with your email! I removed it, so since it has been posted here for two days you might want to change your password ASAP!

Answer (score 0):

Your Mail class is creating a new MimeMessage each time, with new MimeBodyParts each time, but you're reusing the same MimeMultipart each time.